# HighChart pie does not display any data

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, highcharts

Pie Chart looks like this:

[image]

Data is there in JSON:

[image]

**EDIT**

From console:

[image]

When i tried it with type of "bar" or "column" chart it works fine.

Still new to this and really appreciate your help, folks!

Django version: 1.10
Python version: 3.6

---

chartViewHigh.html

```
{% block main %}

    <h1 align="center">Analysis</h1>


{% block content %}

    <div id="container" style="width:50%; height:400px;"></div>

{% endblock %}

{% block extrajs %}
<script>
   var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/';

   var labels = [];
   var defaultData = [];
   var labels2 = [];
   var defaultData2 = [];

   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: endpoint,
       /**
        * @param data
        * @param data.labels   
        * @param data.default
        * @param data.default2
       */

       success: function (data) {
            labels = data.labels;
            defaultData = data.default;
            labels2 = data.labels2;
            defaultData2 = data.default2;
            setChart()
        },
        error: function (error_data) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    });

    function setChart() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var chart = {
                     plotBackgroundColor: null,
                     plotBorderWidth: null,
                     plotShadow: false
                };
                var title = {
                     text: 'Total'
                 };
                var tooltip = {
                     pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                  };
                var plotOptions = {
                     pie: {
                         allowPointSelect: true,
                         cursor: 'pointer',
                     dataLabels: {
                         enabled: true,
                         format: '<b>{point.name}%</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                          style: {
                              color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                          }
                     }
                }
            };
            var series= [{
               type: 'pie',
               name: 'Group share',
               data: [
                   { name: 'Board',   y: defaultData },
                  {
                     name: 'Member',
                     y: defaultData2,
                     sliced: true,
                     selected: true
                  }
               ]
            }];

            var json = {};
            json.chart = chart;
            json.title = title;
            json.tooltip = tooltip;
            json.series = series;
            json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
            $('#container').highcharts(json);
         });
```

---

views.py

```
 class ChartData(APIView):
     def get(self, request, format=None):
        qs_count = Administrator.objects.filter(association=self.request.user.association).count()
        qs_count2 = Member.objects.filter(association=self.request.user.association).count()

        labels = ["Members"]
        default_items = [qs_count2]
        labels2 = ["Board"]
        default_items2 = [qs_count]

        data = {
           "labels": labels,
           "default": default_items,
           "labels2": labels2,
           "default2": default_items2
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: Your data is has incorrect format (it might be strings instead of numbers). Can paste it here?

Comment: @morganfree - Where do you want the data from? Console? I have edited it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data array has incorrect format. `y` values must be numbers, you set them as an array.

Change series variable to:

```
 var series= [{
           type: 'pie',
           name: 'Group share',
           data: [{ 
       name: 'Board',   
       y: defaultData[0] },
              {
                 name: 'Member',
                 y: defaultData2[0],
                 sliced: true,
                 selected: true
              }
           ]
        }];
```

Or send those values as a single number instead of an array.

Comment: God catch on that since i miss it xD THANK YOUUU!!!
Also, if you could help me with this problem that would be much appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023377/how-to-make-the-chart-display-current-year-with-month-in-highchart-x-axis

Answer (score 0):

You look to be missing in your chart section a declaration of a pie chart.

```
           var chart = {
                 plotBackgroundColor: null,
                 plotBorderWidth: null,
                 plotShadow: false,
                 type: 'pie' // this is missing.
            };
```

Have not been able to run your code to test but fingers crossed this sorts it for you.

Comment: Sorry, that was not it. Since it is mentioned in `var series` Thanks for helping me and gave it a try =)

Comment: Yes sorry, just rested and you are totally correct.